# redis - How to get the number of keys from SCAN command?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redis

I am trying to count the keys matching a pattern. I did get the returned keys from using the `SCAN` command. But instead of getting the keys array, I only want to get the count of the keys.

```
SCAN 0 MATCH tick:klays:umc:*
```

I am using this `INCR` to increment the key `tick:klays:umc:278` like below:

```
INCR tick:klays:umc:278
INCR tick:klays:umc:260
INCR tick:klays:umc:279
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DBSIZE`](https://redis.io/commands/dbsize/) command:

```bash
> DBSIZE
(integer) 0
> SET key value
OK
> DBSIZE
(integer) 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From somewhere on the internet:

KEYS vs SCAN

The SCAN function was created to break up the blocking KEYS command which could present major issues when used in production. Many Redis users know too well the consequences of this slowdown on their production workloads. The KEYS command and SCAN command can search for all keys matching a certain pattern.

In your scenario, it seems like you want the count of the keys that matches the given pattern. Meaning, you want them all at one go. If that is the case, you must be using `KEYS` command rather than `SCAN`.

So, you might want to use keys & count the result in JavaScript.

```
const keys = await client.keys('tick:klays:umc:*');
const count = keys.length; // 280
```

You must also remember that, `KEYS` is a blocking operation as mentioned above. So, be aware of the performance. If number of the keys can keep grow, you might want to keep a counter for them in redis.

Comment: I learned the `KEYS` could block operation. That's why I didn't use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the [INFO](https://redis.io/commands/info/) command. It returns stats on Redis, including how many keys there are:

```bash
> SET foo bar
OK
> SET bar baz
OK
> SET baz qux
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> INFO KEYSPACE
# Keyspace
db0:keys=3,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

You'll have to do a bit of parsing, but the value is in there.

Comment: I don't want to get all the keys.

Comment: Ah. Ya. Well then, sorry for the crappy answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my use case and experience, as it is similar to yours.

In my scenario, I need to gather statistics every month. Using the KEYS command is not advisable in a production environment, and the SCAN command can be time-consuming, adding extra load to my Redis.

To address this, I've written a script that transfers the dump.rdb file from Redis to a lower-priority node each month. On this node, I run a Python script to parse that file and count the keys for multiple patterns, and then send the results to my email.

This approach avoids disturbing the production environment.

Answer (score -1):

The `SCAN` command in Redis is used to incrementally iterate over a set of elements (keys in this case). It's a cursor-based iterator, which means it returns elements in a piecemeal fashion, rather than all at once. This is particularly useful for large datasets where returning all keys at once with a command like `KEYS` could block the server.

However, the `SCAN` command itself does not directly tell you the total number of keys. It provides a way to iterate through keys, returning a subset of keys along with a new cursor in each call. You would typically continue calling `SCAN` until the cursor returns to 0, indicating that the iteration is complete.

To count the number of keys using `SCAN`, you would need to iterate over all the keys and maintain a count on the client side. Here is a basic outline of how you might do this:

1. Initialize a cursor to 0 and a variable to hold the count of keys.
2. Use the `SCAN` command with the current cursor.
3. Add the number of keys returned by `SCAN` to your count.
4. Update the cursor with the one returned by `SCAN`.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until the cursor returned by `SCAN` is 0.

Note that this process can be resource-intensive on large datasets, so it should be used judiciously. Also, since Redis is a live database, the total number of keys might change between iterations if keys are added or deleted.